# What are these plants growing on my lawn?

Tags: identification, lawn-repair

I have these leaves sprouting all over my lawn and property. What is it? Should I be worried?

NOTE: This is in Wisconsin.

[image: Mystery Plant]

Comment: When  you pull up one of these mature looking leaves are there roots attached?  Could you send a picture of one leaf with roots?  What are the trees nearby or perennials?  Any of them look like the parent of this leaf?  Too weird.

Comment: I don't have any pictures at the moment but I will try to get some. None of the perennials nearby look like the leaves. They seem to only be growing near the edges of the lawn where trees are nearby (shaded parts). They are also growing in the wooded area but in much larger amounts. I think the trees nearby are Maple/Oak/Ash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How I envy you.  To get this plant to grow in my garden I have to buy bulbs and nurture them along.  This plant is the yellow trout lily, [Erythronium americanum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erythronium_americanum), a native bulb and a real treasure.

The best thing to do with these is nothing.  They do not transplant well and have specific requirements of moist deciduous woods that are hard to meet.

This plant also has a neat habit.  It comes up in early spring, flowers and then disappears for the rest of the year.

Comment: Oh wow! I will try to remember to post an update with a picture of them when they are in full bloom. I'm just happy they aren't poisonous or weeds!

Comment: Worth noting (while noting that it's deprecated and inaccurate, since it's not a violet at all) that another common name for the plant is "Dogtooth Violet" - "Trout Lily" is the more proper current common name.

Comment: Way cool kevinsky!!  Great job!